# Is “girl” a valid synonym for “young woman”?

Tags: synonyms, pejorative-language, connotation, register

This question [emerged out of a discussion on Mastodon](https://cybre.space/@rick_777/102565986041949058) about *Ivanka Trump* being called a girl, where it was claimed that “girl' is synonymous with 'young woman' in English”.

Is this true?
Is it sexism if adult women are called "girls"?

Comment: 'Synonym' just means 'here's a suggestion that might replace your first word, but is not necessarily identical and replaceable in all contexts. You'll need to use judgment to see if it'll replace OK'.

Comment: Context matters; elderly women can be referred to as *girls*, and it is no more sexist than referring to men as "boys".

Comment: Sometimes "girl" and "young woman" mean the same thing, but sometimes not.  You should be able to find more in a dictionary.  FOR EXAMPLE, even if a group of women call each other "girls", they may be offended if some random man calls them that.

Comment: This sounds a bit ranty. Could you add some research and context to this particular case?

Comment: My wife just told me she was going out to lunch "with the girls". I said to her...you are all over 50. She replied..."we are girls if we wanna be."

Comment: See also [A word to describe a female between girl and woman](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83765/is-there-a-word-to-describe-female-between-girl-and-woman)

Comment: Ivanka Trump is not a young woman, she's 37. But in the context of the discussion you linked to I think the intention was to portray her as a spoiled child in terms of attitude and knowledge, in contrast to her chronological age.

Comment: I don't get it... how is this question primarily opinion based? It's complicated and the subject could elicit opinions, but the answers aren't necessarily opinion based. @marcellothearcane

Comment: @Mitch it's the nearest I could find to 'depends so much on context that there's not going to be a right answer'.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Oh. Yeah, that sounds reasonable. When one is closing one is looking for the closest reason which may not be accurate, but when you see the reason one takes it as literally as possible.

Comment: @Mitch does [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262788/5868894) apply on this site?

Comment: @nnnnnn 37 may no longer be in the first flush of youth but it's still young! And family and friends still referred to me as a "girl" when I was 40 (I add modestly, today it's a completely different tale, more like a nan than anything else)

Comment: @marcellothearcane But one can specify those contexts and what the effect of the word has in each of those contexts. I still think this is answerable (and Taliesin does it well, though he didn't address 'sexism' directly, which might give room for more answers).

Comment: For addition to a possible answer, 'girl' might be used in a pejorative sense (wittingly or not) to belittle someone (not unlike 'boy'). I'm not sure if it is sexism to do so (unless it is your boot camp commander yelling at you using it), but it is certainly some kind of '-ism'.

Comment: @Cascabel I mean that Talieson's answer is sooo good, that the question should be left open. On the other hand, the review process has halted because three reviewers have voted to keep the OP closed. So..., if no one sees the question in the review queue, and no one bumps this post or an answer,  it's even more unlikely it will be reopened. Only 1 more vote left!

Comment: It's highly context-dependent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a necessary disclaimer: context and audience matter a lot in what is considered insulting. For instance, two people may interpret being called *girl* differently; calling a coworker or boss a *girl* has different connotations compared to calling your best friend a *girl*. This answer will not attempt to parse all of the nuances of context. Rather, it will give a general answer that (a) *girl* is sometimes used to refer to young women and (b) it is sometimes classified as offensive.

### Young Women / Offensive?

I start with the Oxford Learner's Dictionary (OLD), because it poses the issue in brief:

> ​ 3. [countable] (sometimes offensive) a young woman
>
> (example) Alex is not interested in girls yet.
>
> (example) He married the girl next door.

**Sometimes offensive**, in a learner's dictionary, is a warning to any language learner: be careful when you use this term. Yet the examples seem harmless in themselves. *The girl next door*, in particular, is practically an archetype or cliché with its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl_next_door). So what makes this meaning of girl potentially offensive?

It comes down to [register](https://www.thoughtco.com/register-language-style-1692038). First, *girl* also refers to children, so calling even a young woman a *girl* may convey connotations of immaturity. This is a line of thought that hearkens back several decades. In short, feminists in the 1960s and 1970s urged people to consider the power imbalances in language choices, which included the colloquial use of *girl* to refer to women in professional situations. By this decade, that expectation has virtually become a social norm, so that someone as standard as *Ask A Manager*'s Alison Green [answers a query](https://www.askamanager.org/2017/05/how-to-speak-up-when-women-in-your-office-are-called-girls.html) about using "girl" in the workplace with this:

> While referring to adult women as “girls” may not be intended to be infantilizing or patronizing, language has power, and girls are rarely taken as seriously as women. Some of the most damaging sexism is subtle because it impacts how we think without us even realizing it.

Second, she also points out a double-standard:

> And for anyone reading who thinks that referring to women as
>   “girls’
>   in a professional context is no big deal, consider how infrequently you hear “we have a boy who codes our emails.”

In the Harvard magazine *[Fifteen Minutes](https://www.thecrimson.com/article/2013/2/21/girl-woman-around-language/)*, anthropology professor Susan Greenhalgh explains that double standard further, as there is no term like *guys* to serve as a middle-ground in register for girls/women:

> "The terms 'male' and 'female' are gender-neutral, but not especially desirable for describing social issues, since they signal biological aspects of gender (...) For college-aged 'males,' we have the helpful term 'guys,' which allows us to avoid both 'men' and 'boys.' For 'females,' there is no similar term (the comparable term, 'gals,' having gone out of fashion a long time ago), forcing us to choose between 'girls' and 'women.'"

So *girls* has to do more work, and accordingly the term introduces more conflict, especially for young women who have an understandable desire to be taken seriously compared to their peers and colleagues. Issues of register thus make using *girl* a risk, especially in more formal or unfamiliar contexts.

### When Is It Okay?

First, set phrases like *girl next door* tend to be okay, albeit in more informal contexts.

Second, even dictionaries document several acceptable uses for *girls*. They usually involve an interpersonal relationship. Here is the OLD again:

> 2. [countable] a daughter
>
> 5. [countable] (old-fashioned) a man’s girlfriend
>
> 6. girls [plural] (used especially as a form of address by women) a woman’s female friends

2 and 6 seem obvious. A parent has very good reasons to see their child as their *girl* or *boy*. Friends are on an equal level, so nights with "the girls" (like nights with "the boys") seem common, and "hey girl" as a form of address from one woman to another fits that pattern. 5, too, is understandable – what one calls one's own partner is often up to those two, and a very personal form of address can be appropriate. So familiarity makes using *girl* more likely.

Otherwise, context and audience take hold. If the term could be understood as referring to someone's maturity level, it is an insult. Similarly, if the person has some degree of status, it can be an insult. There may be other risks, including an audience's personal experiences with the term and their current status. Because communication is affected by both context and audience, my advice is to understand them both as well as is feasible before saying something that may insult others.

Comment: I agree with everything in this answer, but I think the point about *girls* as a female version of *guys* could be made a little more clearly.  Are you trying to say that it's a problem ("double standard") that the female equivalent of *guy* is *girl*? Or are you just pointing out that complication?

Comment: I believe “condescending” is the word you’re looking for.

Comment: Great answer. Also, I guess, it's a good idea to mention that in many cases, when you're referring to multiple people, you can easily avoid the term 'girl', because you have people of different genders anyway in that group, so instead of saying 'guys and girls' you may also just say 'people'.